# One word for a state which is neither here nor there

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word to describe a situation in which one is undecided about the relative desirability of two mutually exclusive alternatives in an abstract sense? 
For example, as regards the relative merits of doing X and not doing X, I have always been in a state of ____. As regards which of the two ideologies is more suited to my temperament, I have been in a state of ______.

"vacillation" is one word I thought about. But "vacillation" seems to be rather  concrete in the sense that it seems to be more apt for common alternatives such as "My vacillation in regard to wearing a suit on that occasion led to a delay in my departure".  Are there other words or phrases or idioms that describe what I have in mind?

Comment: A state of neutrality.  But that's a little grandiose for not caring one way or another.  Six of one, half a dozen of another.  Es macht mir nicht, I think the Germans say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try ***ambivalence***

Defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambivalence) as:

> 1
>   :  simultaneous and contradictory attitudes or feelings (such as attraction and repulsion) toward an object, person, or action felt ambivalence toward his powerful father ambivalence toward marriage
>
> 2
>   a :  continual fluctuation (as between one thing and its opposite)
>   b :  uncertainty as to which approach to follow ambivalence about their goals

Answer (score 5):

### Limbo

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/limbo) has four variations on what you want:

> 2a : a place or state of restraint or confinement
>
> 2b :  a place or state of neglect or oblivion
>
> 2c :  an intermediate or transitional place or state
>
> 2d :  a state of uncertainty

Here's an example I've contrived:

> *My travel plans are **in limbo** until one of the companies I interviewed with makes me an offer*.

Comment: I thought of "limbo" but the only meanings I saw in wordweb did not include 2d. "limbo" is right.